TypeError: test_quantity_item_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'
I have this issue in my code using Selenium and Python
I receive this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 38, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 153, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 164, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 207, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 192, in loadTestsFromName
    test = obj()
           ^^^^^
TypeError: test_quantity_item_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'

I configured the chromedriver path in my system, and configured it in my code but still got the same error.
@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


